# Free alternative to Brush Script

Tags: font-recommendation, open-source

Is there an alternative to [Brush Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brush_Script) which looks similar but is available under a FOSS license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a Type 1 version of Brush Script from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/brushscr) and use a program such as [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/) to convert it to OpenType.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for! Depending on the platform, converting may not even be necessary – Linux can deal with it natively, and to my knowledge, so can Windows.